# How to cite Andy Warhol's Marilyn

Tags: citations, thesis

In one of the images I made to illustrate my PhD thesis, I included a "Marilyn" by Andy Warhol (image below), and I cannot find the museum/collection where the painting is exhibited. How should I cite it? Should I change the painting?

[image]

Comment: Is this social sciences or image processing?  If the latter, you should credit the original painting but the more important citation is of the digitization you used as your algorithm input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original of this piece (the Marilyn Diptych) is held in the Tate Gallery in London.

Your question is rather serendipitous as in two days you can buy your own [Warhol original print from the screen at auction](https://onlineonly.christies.com/s/andy-warhol-marilyn/lots/245?cid=EM_SEM|ACCT:Christies20th21stCenturyCulture|CMP:GenericWarholMarilynMay16UK|AG:AndyWarholWorksGeneralBroad|ENGINE:GOOGLE|NT:SEARCH|RG:UK|BANNER:|IMG:|KW:%2Bwarhol%20%2Bmarilyn|MT:b|SID:13232). The sale prints were recently exhibited at the Rockefeller Centre.

I would cite the art work in the following manner:

> Warhol, Andy (1962), *Marilyn Diptych*, Silkscreen on Canvas, Tate Gallery, London.

---

<sub>References:</sub>

<sub>(1) Wikipedia (2016), *Marilyn Diptych*, [Online] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_Diptych, [Accessed 1 May 2016]</sub>

<sub>(2) Tate Gallery Illustrated Companion (2016), *Marilyn Diptych 1962*, [online] http://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/warhol-marilyn-diptych-t03093/text-illustrated-companion [Accessed 1 May 2016]</sub>

Comment: I'm not so sure. Warhol did several Marilyn silkscreens, and the one at the Tate seems to be a different color scheme. I know I also saw some originals at the Andy Warhol Museum in Pittsburgh.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't cite the original. Just as you need to cite facsimile reprints as such, this should be as well, unless they took a picture or scanned the original themself.